# How to apply a randomized transformation to a DataFrame column in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two Data Frames in the following format in CSV files:

data

```
col1  value
a1    100
a2    200
a3    250
a2    1
a1    10
a3    510
...
```

rates

```
id    target    rate
a1    x1        .5
a1    x2        .5
a2    x3        .2
a2    x2        .2
a2    x4        .6
a3    x5        1
```

File are read by the following method

```
data_df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load(data_filepath)
```

and

```
rate_df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load(rate_filepath)
```

As the next step, I'd like to apply a transformation to data_df to generate a data frame like:

final

```
col1  value
x2    100
x3    200
x5    250
x2    1
x2    10
x5    510
...
```

Basically, for each value in the col1 table I want to run an independent random simulation based on the *rates* data frame. So in the example above the first entry, was a1 so based on the rates df it had a 50% chance of becoming x1 and a 50% chance of becoming x2 etcetera.

How can I implement this functionality given that I am working with PySpark Data Frame objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I either don't follow perfectly, or your final output has some mistakes. Either way, this should get you to where you need

```
data.join(rate, data.col1 == rate.id)
  .rdd.map(lambda row: (row.id, (row.value, row.target, row.rate))
  .groupByKey()
  .map(lambda (k, v): RandomOperation(v))
```

where `RandomOperation` takes an `Iterable` of objects `(value, target, rate)`. Simply run your random operations and return what you want.